# cbtransfer to csv is different in version 5.1 comparing to 4.5

Tags: couchbase

When we are running cbtransfer command to get the content from Couchbase in csv format we see the difference in version 4.5 and 5.1. In 4.5 it was created with new line after each tag where in 5.1 it is one line per JSON. 
Is there any way in 5.1 the get it with new line like in 4.5?

Answer (score 0):

CSV format output from cbtransfer has not changed in any version of Couchbase Server. I would recommend checking how the data was inserted into Couchbase Server between the two versions.